# Visual studio: Ignored exceptions not working as expected

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

How can i actualy ignore javascript known thrown exceptions

I have this known exception throw

[image: javascript thrown error]

Then i have theese selected in Exception Settings

[image]

Can anyone help me, this breaks are being kind unbearable